# generate id from varchar to int sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table with field name KodePosition varchar data type. 
when data with the value of |001| then, input new data, why the return data |2|???
 I want the data is |002|.

this is my code, so what i do to be fix ?

```
        SqlConnection.Open();
        String query = "Select max(KodePosition) from Position";
        SqlCommand.Connection = SqlConnection;
        SqlCommand.CommandText = query;            
        int kdPos = Convert.ToInt32(SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());
        int NewkdPos = kdPos + 1;
        return NewkdPos;
```

Please help, thanks... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are returning an integer so leading 0's will not be included.  If you want the leading zeros you will have to return a nchar or varchar that is formatted.  Try returning:

```
return ("000" + NewkdPos.ToString()).Substring(NewkdPos.ToString().Length, 3);
```

Comment: Remember you are returning a string now not an integer.  If you cast it back to an integer you will loose the leading zeros.